# Random number concentrated within a certain range

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran

I wrote Fortran code to generate a series of random numbers. In this code, I could set up random number window (minimum and maximum random number) and percentage of random numbers within this window (number of random numbers). I want that the generated random numbers are always different from each other.

I could use gfortran compiler to compile it successfully; however, I found a problem. For instance, when I input 1 and 81 as minimum and maximum values respectively and 0.07 as the percentage, the code always gave me seven different random numbers, which were always smaller than 10, no matter how many times I ran it. What I expect is that the code should give me seven different random numbers which are distributed within 1~81 range, rather than only concentrated within 1~10 range. I do not know why the code gave me the random numbers only concentrating within a certain range. I paste my code below.

Would you anyone give me some suggestions on my problem? Thank you very much in advance.

```
   PROGRAM RANDOM_POSITION
   IMPLICIT NONE
   REAL percent, val
   INTEGER maxi, mini, num, i, l
   INTEGER, DIMENSION(1), ALLOCATABLE :: position(:)
   PRINT *,'Range for the impurity position(maximum and minimum value):'
   PRINT *,'Minimum value:'
   READ (UNIT=*, FMT=*) mini
   PRINT *,'Maximum value:'
   READ (UNIT=*, FMT=*) maxi
   PRINT 11,'Percentage of impurity='
   11 FORMAT(A23,$)
   READ (UNIT=*, FMT=*) percent
   num = (maxi-mini) * percent
   IF ((maxi-mini) * percent-num  .NE. 0.0) THEN
      num = num + 1
   END IF
   PRINT *, num
   ALLOCATE (position(num))
   CALL RANDOM_SEED()
   DO i=1, num ,1
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(val)
      position(i) = NINT(mini + val * num)
      CALL JUDGEMENT(position, i, l)
      l = 0
      DO WHILE (l .EQ. 0)
               CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(val)
               position(i) = NINT(mini + val * num)
               CALL JUDGEMENT(position, i, l)
      END DO      
      PRINT *, position(i)
   END DO
   DEALLOCATE(position)
   STOP
   END PROGRAM RANDOM_POSITION
   SUBROUTINE JUDGEMENT(arr, j, l)
   IMPLICIT NONE
   INTEGER j, k, l
   INTEGER, DIMENSION(1) :: arr(j)
   l = 1
   DO k=1, j-1, 1
      IF (arr(k) .EQ. arr(j)) THEN
         l = 0
         EXIT
      ELSE
         l = 1
      END IF
   END DO
   RETURN
   END SUBROUTINE JUDGEMENT
```

Comment: I haven't thought much about your question, but you have `l=0` followed by a loop with a `l.eq.0` condition.  In that loop the value of `l` appears never to change.

Comment: 19 is exactly the result for `num=(maxi-mini)*percent`. What do you expect to get?

Comment: Dear All, Thank you very much for the answer. I found out the fault finally. I alter parameter l value in subroutine but I did not transfer it between main code and subroutine when I call the subroutine. Then l value is always same and the loop just keeps on the continuation and never jumps out. I have sorted it out. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your code still has errors. For example, you don't roll again when the rolled number is already in the array, you just check again. This may lead to an infinite loop. Also, if you want numbers between `mini` and `maxi`, you should use `x = mini + val*(maxi - mini + 1)`

Comment: Dear All,

I revised my FORTRAN code and paste it in my question; however, when I ran it, I found another problem. I update my question. Would you please have a look at it and give me some suggestions on how to sort it out? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you need to be more specific about your problem (not to mention fixing the error that was pointed to you a week ago ).

Comment: Mr. agentp, Thank you very much for the suggestion. I changed the topic name of my question. Is it fine?